# Would the following code be optimized to one function call?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I have very little (read no) compiler expertise, and was wondering if the following code snippet would automatically be optimized by a relatively recent (VS2008+/GCC 4.3+) compiler:

```
Object objectPtr = getPtrSomehow();

if (objectPtr->getValue() == something1)       // call 1
    dosomething1;
else if (objectPtr->getValue() == something2)  // call N (there are a few more)
    dosomething2;

return;
```

where getValue() simply returns a member variable that is one of an enum. (The call has no observable effect)

My coding style would be to make one call before the "switch" and save the value to compare it against each of the somethingX's, but I was wondering if this was a moot point with today's compilers.

I was also unsure of what to google to find the answer to this myself.

Thank you,

AK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the compiler can examine the definition of `getValue()` while it compiles that piece of code, it can't elide the second call because it doesn't know whether that call has observable effects and whether it returns the same value the second time around.

Even if it sees the definition, it *probably* (this is my wild guess from having a few peeks at some compilers' internals) won't go out of its way to check that. The only chance you stand is the implementation being trivial *and* inlined twice, and *then* caught by common subexpression elimination. **EDIT:** Since the definition is in the header, and quite small, it's likely that this (inlining and subsequent CSE) will ocurr. Still, if you want to be sure, check the output of `g++ -O2 -S` or your compiler's equivalent.

So in summary, you shouldn't *expect* the optimization to occur. Then again, `getValue` is probably quite cheap, so it's unlikely to be worth the manual optimizations. What's an extra line compared to a couple of machine cycles? Not much, in most cases. If you're writing code where it is much, you shouldn't be asking but just checking it (disassembly/profiling).

Comment: Right, I will of course run timing tests on the result, but was unsure if this was even an area to worry about - there are millions of these calls made, and we are right now looking to improve cycle count anywhere possible in this sub-project. For future reference, is "elide" the terminology for this type of optimization?

Comment: @AK4749 "Elide" is one term used in this area, yes (cf. copy elision). As for performance: Are you *sure* you have to go micro-optimizing? Architectural changes (cf. data-oriented programming), and algorithmic improvements (stupid example: don't call it a million times) may yield greater improvements. A static call is a couple of cycles, that's not normally something you need to optimize.

Comment: Oh no not at all, which is why I asked SO before starting a large build to profile that one segment (which is tough to get called). The new library I will be integrating will, however, require modifications to nearby code, and I was wondering if a sneaky "integration-required change" would be valuable - looks like it is but only from a stylistic/maintainability standpoint

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no control over how it is called, that is the result of maddeningly inept clients ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's not moot, especially if the method is mutable.

If `getValue` is not declared `const`, the call can't be optimized away, as subsequent calls could return different values.

If it is declared `const`, it's easier, but also **not trivial** for the compiler to optimize the call. It would need access to the implementation, to make sure the call doesn't have side effects. There's also the chance that it returns a different value even if marked `const` (modifies and returns a global).

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed declared const, but I'll anyway attempt to put in a low priority modification request because you say it is not trivial. - I'll come back to mark this accepted later as per SO guidelines

Comment: `const`ness is practically irrelevant here. A `const` method of an object without `mutable` members might still launch a nuke.

Comment: @delnan of course, I'm saying if it's declared `const` the compiler might actually try to make some sense of it, and if it's a simple `return 0;` optimize it away. But no, const-ness in no way guarantees optimization (it just moderately hints it).

Comment: Ah, you're assuming the compiler can see the definition? That's rarely a given except with templates.

Comment: Hmm, @delnan and the edit - would you care to explain? Don't quite get the nuke reference haha sorry. But I think I get it: while it is "obvious" to us, there is no way for the compiler to be sure that another thread has not pointed to this object and modified its member variable?

Comment: @delnan not assuming... taking into account.

Comment: @delnan - OP says, "*The call has no observable effect*".

Comment: Well.. it is an implicitly inlined call, I believe as it is defined in the class declaration in the header - `...getValue() const { return val; }`

Comment: @AK4749 - it is likely that the code will be optimized to zero function calls.

Comment: @Robᵩ But the compiler doesn't know that (it has no observable effect).

Comment: @AK4749 if it's like that, it probably will be optimized. **But** i'd still call it only once and have a switch there.

Comment: @delnan see AK's comment - it's trivial.

Comment: Thanks all, looks like it may be a better practice, but lower-priority fix given all the (quick!) information.

Comment: Whether the function is `const` or not is irrelevant.  The question is whether the function is a true function, which doesn't modify state, period.  A `const` function can modify state, and a non-`const` isn't required to modify state.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Eric below shows a way to hint to the compiler exactly what you said. Without the hint, how does a compiler determine a pure function? - though I guess this is why Luchian states that this is a non-trivial operation.

As a side note, while I think the comments here are the most useful, I think for any future passersby the other answer may have more value, so I've marked that one instead, sorry. Let me know if consensus is to the contrary

Comment: @AK4749 "how does a compiler determine a pure function": with flow analysis.  It's not that difficult.

Comment: @JamesKanze forgive me, I have no compiler knowledge whatsoever. The wiki page is quite revealing however, and man these things are remarkable haha

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have noted, the compiler generally cannot eliminate the second call since there may be side effects.

However, some compilers have a way of telling the compiler that the function has no side effects and that this optimization is allowed. In GCC, a function may be declared **pure**. For example:

`int square(int) __attribute__((pure));`

says that the function has “no effects except to return a value, and [the] return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables.”

Comment: Neat. But I have to wonder, is applying this save if the result depends on some mutable `this->member`? It appears `o.pureFunc(); o.member = ...; o.pureFunc();` would call `pureFunc` with the same `this` pointer every time, which seems sufficient to (wrongly) deduce "both calls return the same result".

Comment: Interesting, I had looked into these "hints" for another purpose (deprecating functions), and was minorly disappointed to see that they are compiler-specific. Given that we only build on 2 platforms however, not a big deal.

Comment: @delnan excellent point. I always assumed that compilers cannot take threading into account for optimization (how can they really?). But then again, that leaves quite a lot of simple functions that would require an explicit non-mutable member declarations to be optimized, would it not? Compiler theory makes my head hurt haha those guys do great work

Comment: @delnan: It **might** be safe depending on how the code uses the mutable members. If your program does not need the changes to the mutable members that a second call would cause, then fine. However, keep in mind that “If you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge.” —Henry Spencer

Comment: @AK4749 My example above doesn't involve threading. Actually, neither do any of my other examples here. In fact, C and C++ compilers usually *don't* take threading into account (a lot). If they see straightforward code without calls to memory barriers, they are allows to optimize the hell out of it. If they see calls to code they don't see, there are many things beside threads (such as I/O and other observable effects) which make optimizations invalid.

Comment: Hahaha this question seems perfect for answering purely through quotes! @delnan I think I should pick up a compiler book given that my job has moved this low level; you seem to have knowledge that would allow me to anticipate these idioms rather than react to them

Comment: @AK4749 Well, I got along fine without a book (on compiler construction specifically). I found useful (in ascending order of accessibility): The llvm-dev and clang-cfe mailing lists (quite technical and LLVM-specific, but occasionally delivers deep insights into what compilers can/can't do and what they're only just learning to do), numerous Stackoverflow questions (not all tagged `compilers`),and AltDevBlogADay (between much design and marketing and high-level algorithms, there are quite a few writers who really know their low-level stuff).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> My coding style would be to make one call before the "switch" and save the value to compare 
>   it against each of the somethingX's, but I was wondering if this was a moot point 
>   with today's compilers.

Yes, it's a moot point.  What the compiler does is it's business.  Your hands will be full trying to write maintainable code without trying to micromanage a piece of software that is far better at its job than any of us will ever hope to be.

Focus on writing maintainable code and trust the compiler to carry out its task.  If your later find your code is too slow, then you can worry about optimizing.

Remember the proverb:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: That "proverb" is actually part of a very well-written and balanced reflection on optimization that says far more (and in a far better phrasing) than 99% of the texts in which this excerpt is cited. Knuth, Structured Programming With GOTO Statements.

Comment: I quite agree, I would never start writing code like this, but stumbled across it while coding a related sub library and wondered if this idiom (littered across the old code) was worth pursuing. Excellent advice, nonetheless.

Comment: @delnan: Knuth is the man!  I wrote "proverb" because it has the nice, folksy wisdom of a proverb.  I definitely did not mean to imply that there were no solid reasons behind it!

Comment: Then you're a fortunate exception in my experience. Rock on :) I'd still like to see a larger excerpt (in particular the 97% bit, which is very useful to prevent overly zealous of the quote).